# Liferay Form post activated only on clicking the submit button 2 times?

Tags: forms, session, liferay, liferay-6

I'm posting password via Liferay form and storing it in session called **"password"**,
when I'm putting the correct password which I made it as a default for now **"1234"** the session gets activated
and when I browse across the pages it's working fine.

But when I'm posting it for the first time, it doesn't work, I need to click 2 times on the button so I can see the data or if I go to another page.

Can anyone here support me in this. This is my full code:

```
<%
String value = BeanParamUtil.getString(article, request, "structureId");
%>

<portlet:actionURL secure="<%= PropsValues.COMPANY_SECURITY_AUTH_REQUIRES_HTTPS || request.isSecure() %>" var="SecondloginURL">
    <portlet:param name="saveLastPath" value="0" />
    <portlet:param name="struts_action" value="/journal_content/view" />
</portlet:actionURL>

<c:choose>
    <c:when test="<%= value.equals(\"10801\") %>">
        <%
            HttpSession session1 = request.getSession(false);
            out.print(session1 + "<br>");
            String sessionId = session1.getId();
            out.print(sessionId + "<br>");
            String foo = (String) session1.getAttribute("password");
            out.print(foo + "<br>");
        %>
        <c:choose>
            <c:when test="<%= !Validator.isNull(foo) %>">
                <h2>this is the second password and it's working</h2>
                <div class="journal-content-article"
                     id="article_<%= articleDisplay.getCompanyId() %>_<%= articleDisplay.getGroupId() %>_<%= articleDisplay.getArticleId() %>_<%= articleDisplay.getVersion() %>">
                    <%= RuntimePortletUtil.processXML(application, request, response, renderRequest, renderResponse, articleDisplay.getContent()) %>
                </div>
            </c:when>
            <c:otherwise>                    
                <aui:form action="<%= SecondloginURL %>" name="auth" method="POST">
                    <aui:input label="Second Password" type="password" name="password" />
                    <aui:button type="submit" value="authenticate" onClick="location.reload(true)" />
                </aui:form>

                <% 
                String pass = request.getParameter("password"); 
                out.println(pass+" = 1234"); 
                %>

                <c:if test="<%= Validator.equals(pass, \"1234\") %>">

                    <%  
                    session1.setAttribute("password","authenticated");
                    %>

                </c:if>
            </c:otherwise>
        </c:choose>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <div class="journal-content-article"
             id="article_<%= articleDisplay.getCompanyId() %>_<%= articleDisplay.getGroupId() %>_<%= articleDisplay.getArticleId() %>_<%= articleDisplay.getVersion() %>">
            <%= RuntimePortletUtil.processXML(application, request, response, renderRequest, renderResponse, articleDisplay.getContent()) %>
        </div>
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

I'm doing a **hook** on the **journal_content/view**

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is when the page is refreshed for the first time after (using `location.reload()`) the session is has not been set till the time you are checking for it and it is being set in the `<otherwise>` block below the condition.

So when you click the second time to reload the session has already set. Even if you just refresh the page the second time without clicking on the button you will find that the session is set.

So one way I can think of is to use `struts-action` hook (if you are using `Liferay 6.1`) to move the setting of the `session` code in the respective View-action class.

Or else

Can try to move the setting of the `session` code before you check for the `foo` string.